# Can I comment on a rejected edit suggestion?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I've recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3193523) to update an invalid url documentation to a correct one, however the edit was rejected with the reason:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

I'm unable to understand why it was considered for rejection - that documentation is important as part of the answer. Is there some way I could comment on the rejected action?

Comment: Maybe if instead of `Updated url` you could have said `Fixed broken URL`. The URLs are so close to the same someone might have thought you were just changing the URL from inline to "See the docs here."

Comment: Yeah, agreed ! That's what I thought. So I was wondering if there is some way I could reply over that rejection ?

Comment: It got approved the second time you suggested it. A good message is really important. A majority of the time I can tell whether I'll probably accept an edit just by how clear the comment is.

Comment: Unfortunately many many reviewers don't bother to actually pay attention to what changes were made, and reject good edits (or accept bad edits) as a result. The review badge incentivize some people to just blast through the reviews quickly, rather than focusing on actually improving the quality of posts. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your suggested edit should have been approved. Where I think the misunderstanding happened (and do not blame yourself for it) was the comment you've left. The reviewers should have paid more attention to the changes you've proposed than the comment you've left. The comment is optional...

If you said *fixed a broken link* then I have no doubts the edit would have gotten approved first time and any rejection would have been inappropriate.

It's good that you brought the topic up here, more people get to see it and maybe they will start paying more attention while reviewing. Also, you benefit from having this discussion because you now know that it's a good idea to provide a good comment while suggesting edits.